# How to skip the header when invoking Select with ConvertFrom-Json?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to parse JSON content with the following code:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri http://localhost/api/foo).Content | ConvertFrom-Json | Select someId
```

And the output I've like:

```
someId                                                                      
---------                                                                      
1234                                                     
5678
```

How I can skip the header in the above output, so I've got only values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty someId`. It will only output the value of that variable.

The default is `-Property` which creates an object with that property, which is why you get the header.